# Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

I am getting following errors in syslog while trying to `systemctl start kube-apiserver`

> Dec  8 16:29:42 mySystem systemd[8722]: kube-apiserver.service: Failed
> to execute command: Permission denied Dec  8 16:29:42 mySystem
> systemd[8722]: kube-apiserver.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning
> /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver: Permission denied Dec  8 16:29:42
> mySystem systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Main process exited,
> code=exited, status=203/EXEC Dec  8 16:29:42 mySystem systemd[1]:
> kube-apiserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

MY sysd config looks like this:

> [Unit] Description=Kubernetes API Server
> Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
>
> [Service] User=kube-apiserver ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver
> \  --advertise-address= \  --allow-privileged=true \
> --apiserver-count=3 \  --audit-log-maxage=30 \  --audit-log-maxbackup=3 \  --audit-log-maxsize=100 \  --audit-log-path=/var/log/audit.log \  --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC \  --bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
> --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.crt \  --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,ServiceAccount \  --enable-swagger-ui=true \  --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true \  --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.crt \  --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/etcd-server.crt \  --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/etcd-server.key \  --etcd-servers=http://:2380 \  --event-ttl=1h \  --encryption-provider-config=/var/lib/kubernetes/encryption-config.yaml \  --kubelet-certificate-authority=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.crt \
> --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.crt \  --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.key \  --kubelet-https=true \  --runtime-config=api/all \  --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/service-account.crt \  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/24 \  --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 \  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.crt \  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.key \  --v=2 Restart=on-failure RestartSec=5
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

For a background I am doing a manual kube deployment for some learning purpose.

Comment: Can you please format your question to be more readable and provide reproducible example with more details/config, info about your environment? What documentation you`re following?

Comment: I got the 203 error code because kubeadm could not work with SELinux on. Turn it off temporarily with `setenforce 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the information that you provided I suspect that you have some permission/privileges issue which indicates this error:

```sh
"Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver: Permission denied"
```

You are trying to start the service with `User=kube-apiserver` which I think don`t have enough privileges.

---

If you wish to learn how to bootstrap Kubernetes cluster by yourself there are two good ways to do that:

1 .  With `Kubeadm` which allows you to create and manage Kubernetes clusters. It performs the actions necessary to get a minimum viable, secure cluster up and running in user friendly way.

Here's [how to install it](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/), and here is information [how to create your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

2. With Kelsey's [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way).  This is a opposite way to kubeadm and it will guide you thru all the step/task of boostraping a Kubernetes cluster.

It has a section about manual [bootsrapping kubernetes cluster with usage of Kubernetes binaries](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md) and section about [API server](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md#configure-the-kubernetes-api-server).

---